# return key pressed inside uitableviewcell swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, textfield

I have a textfield in each cell of my tableview. I want to quit keyboard when users pressed on the return key. I tried:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
```

But it doesn't work and I can't seem to find a away to reference the textfield inside the cell of my tableview. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have created `IBOutlets` of your textfield in your cell class.
Give your textfield delegate to self in `cellForRow` datasource method of `UITableView`

```
cell.yourTextField.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give delegate form storyboard.

Answer (score -1):

You should let your custom `UITableViewCell` class to confirms to `UITextFieldDelegate`:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    // ...
}
```

In `awakeFromNib` you should your textfields delegate to the cell class:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    // ...

    textField.delegate = self

    // ...
}
```

Finally, implement `textFieldShouldReturn`:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: this is wrong. If in `awakeFromNib` it is implemented, it will not be a part of `ViewController` and only be a part of custom cell, the textfield is in table. It should be in `cellForRow`

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari From architectural perspective, letting the *Controller layer* to handle the cell's components is not a good idea, this emphasizes the *"Massive View Controllers"* theory.

Comment: Brother, it has to do with `self`. You can't make self to customcell class. If you are making , then you have to implement `UITextFieldDelegate` in custom cell. And its not about components. You can handle the designing layout stuff in `awakeFromNib` but in case of delegate, there comes the ownership. If you are implementing delegate to self in custom cell class, then you have to pass this again via delegate in your `ViewController` which acts as extra overhead.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari I hope that you are not upset of this discussion because I am not at all :) Confirming that textFieldShouldReturn implemented in the custom cell class, "If you are implementing delegate to self in custom cell class, then you have to pass this again via delegate in your ViewController which acts as extra overhead" could you please try to make it by yourself (add a textfield to cell and implement, add textField.delegate = self to awakeFromNib and implement textFieldShouldReturn), it works fine without the need of passing it to the controller.

Comment: what if something needs to be changed in `ViewController`, lets say a button color to be changed or say some label needs to be updated, which is a part of ViewController` whenever return key is pressed. Then you need to pass something from `textFieldShouldReturn` delegate to your controller class. Basically another delegate or some notification or some closure

Comment: I don't know whether you got upset this time mate:) kidding. I was seriously waiting for your reply. If you have any good suggestion or anything to share which will improve the context, I would be more than happy to learn and accept.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari not at all! your last response was enough to let me understand what do you mean. But now I'm thinking that the controller will contains much things to do! not only its own behaviors but also other classes; Do you think MVVM is exist for those types of issues? And you are right btw, ui stuff should be coded in awakeFromNib or I prefer to be in layoutSubViews.

Comment: Yes, MVVM is a good option and I have seen some of the app's code in MVVM but generally iOS apps follow the complete MVC. The components hereby becomes the part of controller itself. Depends of the Model which you are making, as we don't consider CustomCells as a complete different model. Again it depends from Devs to Devs. You are free to follow any approach.